# Yocto initramfs does not have enough space in rootfs during flashing

Tags: linux, yocto-project

I have been trying to build a Linux image for imx6ull with Yocto. I have successfully built an older version and flashed the board using mfgtool. With Linux Gatesgarth branch i have been having problems with mfgtool so I am trying to switch to uuu.

First part of the uuu script is below;

```
uuu_version 1.2.39

# This command will be run when i.MX6/7 i.MX8MM, i.MX8MQ
SDP: boot -f u-boot.imx

FB: ucmd setenv fastboot_buffer ${loadaddr}
FB: download -f zImage
FB: ucmd setenv fastboot_buffer ${fdt_addr}
FB: download -f imx6ull-14x14-evk-gpmi-weim-imx6ull14x14evk.dtb
FB: ucmd setenv fastboot_buffer ${initrd_addr}
FB: download -f fsl-image-mfgtool-initramfs-imx6ull14x14evk.cpio.gz.u-boot
FB: ucmd setenv bootargs ${bootargs} ${mtdparts}
FB: acmd ${kboot} ${loadaddr} ${initrd_addr} ${fdt_addr}

FBK: ucmd cat /proc/mtd
FBK: ucmd cat /proc/mtd | while read dev size erase name; do mtd=${dev:3}; mtd=${mtd%:}; name=${name%\"}; name=${name#\"}; echo export $name=$mtd >> /tmp/mtd.sh; done;
```

At this point device gives "No space left on device" error.

```
run shell cmd: cat /proc/mtd | while read dev size erasesize name; do mtd=${dev:3}; mtd=${mtd%:}; name=${name%\"}; name=${name#\"}; echo export $name=$mtd >> /tmp/mtd.sh; done;
sh: line 0: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

I am testing with a bare image with a 512mb nand flash but it seems like rootfs partition is full.

```
1:243>Start Cmd:FBK: ucmd echo "`df -h`"
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           31M   31M     0 100% /
none             31M     0   31M   0% /dev
```

I have tried to increase the size of the partition with `IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "1.5"` in local.conf but the error persists.

How can i increase the size of the rootfs partition in initramfs or what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: The usual solution is to use _tmpfs_ and perhaps some overlay filesystem if you want everything to be writable. But I have no idea about any of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: A more detailed version of the same question is [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Imx6ull-Mfgtool-can-t-flash-UTP-or-UDC-problem/m-p/1280668/highlight/true#M174414)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting cma size to 0 in kernel menuconfig solved the problem.
Config line is `CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=0`